# Using variable as a part of an URL with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, url

How can I make the following code work with Vue.js?

```
<a href="http://{{ company }}.com">Google</a>
```

where company is google.

```
data: {
   company: "google"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      company: 'google'
    };
  },

});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.1/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <a :href="`http://${company}.com`">Google</a>
    </div>
```